# Network Issues with LEMP set up through WSL using PHP, Composer, NPM

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hope everyone is well

I have set up a LEMP environment on Ubuntu 18.04 WSL. I am using PHP7.1-FPM, Composer and NPM for an application running from a webserver.

I have set up the virtual host file and can browse to the webpage and open the application and connect to the database over localhost:80. But my issue is, it feels like there is almost a timeout on the LEMP setup. On the application, there is a 60-second timer where it automatically refreshes and pulls updated information from the MySQL database. If I press the inbuilt button to refresh it, that seems to work fine, but the minute it tries to do an automatic refresh, it throws up an error saying:

net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
Uncaught (in promise ) Error: Network Error
at e.explorts
at XMLHttpRequest.f.onerror

I did try adding proxy buffers:

```
             proxy_buffers 8 1024k;
             proxy_buffer_size 1024k;
```

I feel as though Windows 10 is playing a part. from my knowlege, port 80 is in use on windows 10 from PID4 HTTP service which is used  by the print spooler but when i set it to a different port, It does  not even connect (1111).

I am just starting out really with this. I have (basic compared to most of you guys) knowledge in troubleshooting but WSL and LEMP is a new frontier to me so any help woul be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is why you want docker for your dev environment. i remember skype used to hog port 80 as well

Comment: Indeed, I mean I do want to configure it for SSL going forward so perhaps that's the way to go. Although, I have disabled that service now through the registry and I am still getting the error through the application.

Comment: If you don't mind using apache, i have one ready to rock! https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2019/04/05/ready-to-rock-php-7-3-docker-lamp-stack/

Comment: (caveat, there is one CLI command which if you are on windows requires an extra forward slash, cant remember which one it is but its easy to sort when you come across it)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the issue is, we use allow override in our vhost but this is not available on Nginx. It would mean me having to convert our vhosts file.

If anyone can assist with this, I would be most great full. In the mean time, I went with apache2 in wsl.